# Over ride the catalog product template in magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I am trying the magento 2 and over ride the product details template as follows:

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\oppo\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view/details.phtml
```

and added some code there but it is not working at it is still showing the the contents from the core module in

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view/details.phtml
```

What is the right way to do so any guide.

Comment: Have you try it with clean magento cache?

Comment: cache is disabled at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To override

/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml,

For this, in app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<body>        
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template"xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::product/view/details.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```